# How to add to import SCSS files in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to ask how to import all my .scss files in one css file. For example i have global scss files like colors.scss, mixins.scss, and helpers.scss. I'm thinking to have one .scss files and I just @import to load all my .scss files. I'm using angular-cli in creating my project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 You create a global `styles.scss` file under `src` directory.

2 Next you add that file to `angular-cli.json` styles array:

```
 "apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": "assets",
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "mobile": false,
            "styles": [
                "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "environments": {
                "source": "environments/environment.ts",
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
```

3 Import all of your .scss files in `styles.scss`

`@import 'styles/colors.scss';`

Comment: I tried it and it wont recognize my for examples my colors variable in my component.scss file

Comment: Have you imported `colors.scss` before `component.scss` in the same file?

Comment: what i mean for component.scss is the scss when you generate a component using ( ng generate component ) for example a header component

Comment: In this case you need to import `colors.scss` in every component .scss, where you reference the variables from `colors.scss`.

Comment: I see, I'm thinking of doing that. But I realised that It will be redundant because what if I use that colors.scss in like 5 components.

Comment: Then you will have to import `colors.scss` in all 5 components, the angular-cli team is aware of that problem. Maybe in the future there will be an upgrade to that, but for now that is how it is.